# How to access ASL (Apple System Log) from macOS Recovery?

Tags: startup

I have trouble booting the MacOS system. It's in constant loop. I don't know how can I access the logs from MacOS Recovery so I can troubleshoot it. Any suggestion?

Can I do SSH to the system?

Comment: Try booting into recovery mode - https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/25/how-to-start-up-your-mac-in-internet-recovery-mode/.

Comment: Apple docs on it - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314.